# Ios Create custom init for NSManagedObject subclass in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift2, subclass, nsmanagedobject, init

### A using IOS9 and Swift2.2

I want to create empty init() as creating a NSManagedObject Variable like

```
let NamTblVar = NamTblCls()
NamTblVar.Nam1Var = "TrlTxt1"
NamTblVar.Nam2Var = "TrlTxt2"
NamTblVar.Nam3Var = "TrlTxt2"
NamTblVar.SevDataFnc(NamTblVar)
```

And write all the save and retrieve functions in custom NSManagedObject Class

I am trying to create custom class but not able to init()
Getting a error: Must call a designated initialiser of the superclass 'NSManagedObject'

I Tried

```
class NamTblCls: NSManagedObject
{
    let ContxtVar = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDgtCls).managedObjectContext

    init()
    {
        super.init()
```

and

```
        super.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("NamTbl", inManagedObjectContext: ContxtVar)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: ContxtVar)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, this is a way you might be able to do it:

```
let title = NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType(rawValue: 0)
let test: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: title!)

class NamTblCls: NSManagedObject
{
    //let ContxtVar = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate).managedObjectContext

    init(){
        super.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("String", inManagedObjectContext: test)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: test)
    }
}
```

(`title` and `test` are for testing in the playground)

But in reality, you should probably setup your `class` like this:

```
class NamTblCls: NSManagedObject
{
    //let ContxtVar = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate).managedObjectContext

    init(entityName: String, someName: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType){
        let test: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: someName)
        super.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: test)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: test)
    }
}
```

And create the `entityName` and `NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType` when you initialize the class.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Am new to stackoverflow and do not have enough reputations yet, So kindly vote for my question up, so i can vote for your ans

Comment: @SujayUN, that is fine, I would be happy with an accept. (It helps me get [this badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero))